# jquery code validation wont work

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

I tried to create a registration form. The form itself works fine but if i try to validate the entries with jquery it will not show any message. What did I forget?

jquery part (just try with username)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#account_erstellen').validate({
        rules: {
            Benutzername: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 10
            }
        },
        message: {
            Benutzername: {
                required: 'Feld kann nicht leer sein',
                minlength: 'Zu kurz',
                maxlength: 'Zulang'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

html part

```
<form id="account_erstellen" method="post" action="mail/account_erstellen.php">
<p>Benutzername:<input name="Benutzername" type="text" size="65" maxlength="30"></p>
<p>Emailadresse:<input name="Emailadresse" type="text" size="65" maxlength="30"></p>
<p>Emailadresse wiederholen:<input name="Emailadresse_2" type="text" size="65" maxlength="30"></p>
<p>Passwort:<input name="Passwort" type="password" size="65" maxlength="30"> </p>
<p>Passwort wiederholen:<input name="Passwort_2" type="password" size="65"  maxlength="30"></p>
<input type="submit" title="Jetzt registrieren" value="Registrierung absenden">
</form>
```

the source for the jquery i got from

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

in ff console i got the error message "validator is undefined"? After searching for it I only read that i maybe load the wrong library?

any suggests ?

Comment: plz create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Working for me http://jsfiddle.net/DDS4X/

Comment: For me too: http://jsfiddle.net/5gFmU/

Comment: i think you may be loading you scripts after form ,please load scripts in head section

Comment: ok no idea why it wont work i tried to copy and paste the same to jsfiddle and it wont work on webspace wont work too but from zword and rafaelsoufraz it works ? really confusing.

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh, since his jQuery is wrapped inside a DOM ready event handler, it does not matter where he loads his scripts.

Comment: What do these jumbled up words mean?  _"the source for the jquery i got from"_ ~  (It's not even a sentence.)  Did you include those three lines in your HTML someplace?

Answer (score 0):

The `messages` option is spelled `messages`, not `message` as you have it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#account_erstellen').validate({
        rules: {
            Benutzername: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 10
            }
        },
        message: {  // <-- this should be spelled 'messages'
            Benutzername: {
                required: 'Feld kann nicht leer sein',
                minlength: 'Zu kurz',
                maxlength: 'Zulang'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Otherwise, your code is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/FWbLq/

---

**File Includes**

You can include your JavaScript files within the `<head>` or the `<body>` section of your HTML.  Since your code is enclosed within a `document.ready` event handler function, it doesn't matter which.  However, there are reasons to believe that page loading performance is enhanced when the scripts are included at the end of the `<body>` section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--// your head content //-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--// your html markup //-->

        <!--// JavaScript file includes //-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, you can include them in the `<head>` like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--// your head content //-->

        <!--// JavaScript file includes //-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--// your html markup //-->
    </body>
</html>
```

The jQuery library itself is always loaded *before* any jQuery plugins.  The jQuery Validate plugin must be loaded before its `additional-methods.js` file.

Comment: ok i did the 2 changes but it still wont work. dont know why cause i tried yesterday with some other jquery function like fadeOut and this works fine...

Comment: @user3115267, you can see it's working in my jsFiddle.   There is nothing posted in your OP that tells us anything relevant.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to generate same problem by including these js file.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

As per my knowledge, There may be following cases:

first case, may be your validate.js does not load properly.

second case, may be you have written your code before include js library that's why your custom code is loaded before loading js library and search for validate method that would not be available at that time and it generate 'jQuery.validator is undefined' error.

Comment: -1, how does including the plugin twice solve anything?